# AutoComplete Textbox stops app and gives Acces Violation error

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms

I've been trying to make an autocompleting textbox,but got the Access Violation error with the app closing(after being stuck a second beforehand)

This is my code:

```
private async void DashBoard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None;
            DatabaseHelpers.DatabaseHelper1.LoadUsers();
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            AutoCompletion();
        }
        private void AutoCompletion()
        {
            string[] CNPS= new string[DatabaseHelpers.DatabaseHelper1.utilizatori.Count];
            foreach (var item in DatabaseHelpers.DatabaseHelper1.utilizatori)
            {
               CNPS.Append(item.CNP.ToString());
            }

            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
                source.AddRange(CNPS);
                AutoCompleteStringCollection collection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                collection.AddRange(CNPS);
                textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collection;
            
        }
```